# Angle Between Vector in Different Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm reading through the paper [Between-Groups Comparison of Principal Components](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286995?seq=1#) by Krzanowski and am struggling to understand one of the first concepts.

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be $p \times n_1$ and $p \times n_2$ datasets, where $p$ is the number of variables and $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of samples in each dataset. Let $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{M}$ be the $k \times p$ principal component loadings for $\mathbf{A}$  and $\mathbf{B}$, respectively.

> *Theorem 1*: The minimum angle between an arbitrary vector in the space of the first k principal components of $\mathbf{A}$ and the one most nearly parallel to it in the space of the first k components of $\mathbf{B}$ is given by $\cos^{-1}\left({\lambda_1^\frac{1}{2}}\right)$ =, where $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{LM'ML'}$.

The first step is to find an expression for the angle between some arbitrary unit column vector $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbf{A}$'s PC subspace and the same vector in $\mathbf{B}$'s PC subspace. To do this, we first transform $\mathbf{a}$ into the original variable space using $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{L}^T\mathbf{a}$ and then transform $\mathbf{b}$ into $\mathbf{B}$'s PC space using the transformation $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{M}\mathbf{b}$. We would now say that the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ satisfies $\cos(\delta) = \mathbf{a^Tc}  = \mathbf{a'Mb} = \mathbf{a'ML'a}$. The paper has a different solution.

> *Proof*: Let $\mathbf{a}$ be an arbitrary (unit) vector with elements $a_1, ..., a_k$ in the subspace generated by the $k$ principal components of $\mathbf{A}$. Its coordinates referred to the original $p$ orthogonal axes are therefore the components of $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{L'a}$. The projection of this vector onto the subspace generated by the first $k$ components of $\mathbf{B}$ is $\mathbf{M'Mb}$, so the angle $\delta(0 \leq \delta \leq \pi)$ between the two satisfies $\cos^2(\delta) = \mathbf{b'M'Mb} = \mathbf{a'LM'ML'a}$.

We start the same, however, instead of simply transforming $\mathbf{b}$ into $\mathbf{B}$'s PC subspace, he transforms then projects it. I don't understand why the projection is necessary. Additionally, I see that his solution uses $\cos^2(\delta)$ instead of $\cos(\delta)$. What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
I think I may have figured it out. $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{L'a}$ transforms $\mathbf{a}$ from $\mathbf{A}$'s PC subspace to $\mathbf{A}$'s original subspace. We don't have a transformation that goes directly from subspace $\mathbf{A}$ to subspace $\mathbf{B}$. Instead, we need to go from $\mathbf{A}$ to the PC subspace of $\mathbf{B}$ using $\mathbf{Mb}$ and then from the PC subspace of $\mathbf{B}$ to $\mathbf{B}$'s regular subspace, using $c = \mathbf{M'Mb}$. We now can compare the angle between $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$.

It is still unclear to me why the solution uses $\cos^2(\delta)$ instead of $\cos(\delta)$.